# Erro de "unwrapping an Optional value swift" em esconder label

Tags: swift

Toda vez que tendo esconder um `label` da minha tela usando `label.isHidden = true` esse erro aparece, já vi em outras perguntas aqui no forum sobre o tema, porem não consegui entender corretamente.

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var txtHE: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtHS: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtHT: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtHL: UILabel!


var esconder:Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    esconder = true

    txtHE.isHidden = esco
    txtHS.isHidden = esco
    txtHT.isHidden = esco
    txtHL.isHidden = esco

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que sua Label ainda não foi carregada na memória e como você colocou um ! na declaração dela, o compilador tenta acessar a Label, e dá erro. Essa exclamação indica que a Label nunca pode estar nula.

Confira se a Label está sendo carregada corretamente no Interface Builder e cheque se a Label não está nula antes de tentar acessa-lá.

Como boa prática, não declare como ! e sim com ? e faça uma checagem toda vez que acessar a Label.

Comment: Ok, vou verificar.